# Treating JSON as a tree structure

Tags: javascript

I have some incoming JSON which consists of only nested maps (no arrays), e.g.,

```
{
    "name1": {
        "name2": "name3",
        "name4": {
            "name5": "name6"
        }
    },
    "name7": "name8"
}
```

Notice that the keys and values here don't follow any particular pattern.

What I want is, given such an object representing the root of a tree, to produce a list of new objects representing the first layer of children, each as a new JSON object.

Comment: If you aren't entirely set on the idea of having nested objects, I'll posit an alternative where you instead insist that:

 - Every Element has an id node (for some specified id property).
 - Each element can specify a parent node with a parent attribute.
 - There is a single node with no parent. This is the root node.

If you provide JSON data in this fashion, it may end up being easier to construct trees in a stream-friendly way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like

```
var obj = {
    "name1": {"name2": "name3", "name4": {"name5": "name6"}},
    "name7": "name8"
}

var result = [], tmp;
for(var key in obj){
    if(obj.hasOwnProperty(key)){
        tmp = {};
        tmp[key] = obj[key];
        result.push(tmp)
    }
}
console.log(result)
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/GQwAw/)

Comment: I changed my entire approach to this, but this does accomplish what the question asked for.

Answer (score 0):

```
function ent(map) {
  var entries = [];
  for (var key in map) 
    entries.push({
      key: key,
      value: map[key]
    });
  return entries;
}

ent({
  "name1": {"name2": "name3", "name4": {"name5": "name6"}},
  "name7": "name8"
})
```